# Can you have an email address with only the top level domain as the domain part?

Tags: email, tld

The question title pretty much contains the question by itself, but as an example:

Instead of having an address like `bob@example.com`(where `example` is the sub-domain of the TLD `com`) could you have have an email address like `sky@net`, where the domain part consists just of `net`, which also happens to be a TLD?

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/154991/why-do-some-tld-have-an-mx-record-on-the-zone-root-e-g-ai

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It is technically possible for the owner of a TLD to add `MX` records in the TLD zone.

This would allow *them* to have email addresses like `bob@example`.

It's, however, not very common to do so and I can only imagine that there are plenty of cases where having such an email address can cause problems (email address validation that doesn't accept such addresses, etc.).

Here's an example of a TLD that currently does have `MX` records:

```
tt.                     86400   IN      MX      1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
tt.                     86400   IN      MX      10 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
```

Comment: I believe there is an ICANN policy against this, but I've not been able to find it on their website. (I also have a vague memory of there having been an email address "ber@se", but that may be a legend I was told of when I started out in the early 90s...)

Comment: I know there is a prohibition against top-level MX records in the new gTLDs, because I personally wrote the code testing for that in the technical approval process. I suspect the requirement is buried somewhere in the vast amount of registration paperwork. It gets slightly more complicated by the addition of an MX record during the new TLD sunrise period (the "you used a name you thought would never be public" warning data), and of course old gTLDs and ccTLDs have much greater freedom to ignore ICANN's opinions.

Comment: Possible, but prohibited: [New gTLD Dotless Domain Names Prohibited](https://www.icann.org/news/announcement-2013-08-30-en)

Comment: @sleske the edit seems a bit pointless, they still have MX records today.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist: Sorry, my mistake. I did a `dig` lookup on `a.root-servers.net`, which does not return an MX record. However, other server do return them. So it seems I don't understand the DNS :-(. Feel free to revert my edit.

Comment: E-mail address validators are _very_ often not complaint with the standard.

Comment: Most clients and validators will accept a single domain label if it ends with a dot, which technically would be the correct notation anyway. In fact I used `nobody@invalid.` as a dummy address on several occasions and got away with it. 